# Stopping an Actor Instance and Waiting for it to Stop

Tags: akka

I have the following piece of code in my Actor's (I call this Actor MasterActor) receive method:

```
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case StopActor(id, actorConfig) =>
      log.info(s"Stopping actor with id = $id and config $actorConfig")

      stopActor(id, powerPlantCfg).pipeTo(self)
      context.become(waitForStop(sender()))

    // Other messages... not shown here for simplicity
  }
```

So what I'm doing above is to stop the actor and pipe the result of that which is a Future[Continue] (where Continue is a Monix Ack type) to the Actor that contains the above Receive method. The stopActor looks like this:

```
  private def stopActor(id: Long, cfg: ActorConfig): Future[Ack] = async {
    await(fetchActor(id).materialize) match {
      case scala.util.Success(actorRef) =>
        log.info(s"Stopping Actor with id = $id")
        context.watch(actorRef)
        context.stop(actorRef)
        Continue
      case scala.util.Failure(fail) =>
        log.error(s"Could not fetch Actor instance for id = $id because of: $fail")
        Continue
    }
  }
```

I'm doing the context.watch(actorRef) and this is how my waitForStop looks like:

```
  private def waitForStop(source: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case Continue =>
      source ! Continue
      context.become(receive)

    case someShit =>
      log.error(s"Unexpected message $someShit received while waiting for an actor to be stopped")
  }
```

So I have 2 questions here:

1. When doing context.become(waitForStop(sender())), I'm closing in on the sender(), so I assume the sender in this case is the ActorRef that contains all this above code which is the MasterActor. Am I correct?
2. How do I know explicitly that this ActorRef that I'm trying to stop is actually stopped so that I can do a context.unwatch(actorRef) as soon as it is stopped?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be notified of the stop of an Actor by watching it. You are already familiar with watch:

```
val kenny = context.actorOf(Props[Kenny], name = "Kenny")
context.watch(kenny)
```

and then you can wait for a Terminated message. Once you receive it, you can unwatch what you need.

```
def receive = {
    case Terminated(kenny) => println("OMG, they killed Kenny")
    case _ => println("Parent received a message")
}
```

So my reccomendation would be to simply watch, become waiting for terminated, and issue the stop command. But I'm unsure what you are asking exactly, so this cvould be the wrong ans
[Blog post example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-monitor-akka-actor-death-with-watch-method)

Comment: Cool! So who would send the Termintaed message? Is it sent by the ActorSystem?

Comment: But I would not send a Stop command after getting a Terminated message as you describe or?

Comment: I would do a context stop, the result of which is the Terminated message being sent and I get this message and do a context unwatch

Comment: Yes. If you want to put the handling of the terminated message in another receive and becoming that before/after sending the stop, you can do that as well (you can become after without worrying about the sync issues bc akka guarantees that you won't get new messages until you are done with the current one, provided after means "before completing this message's processing", and not in a scheduled thing later)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I sort of did not quite unerstand it!